What sort of trust for gift from UK grandparent to US grandchildren
My mother in the UK is looking to minimise UK inheritance tax by gifting approximately $50K each to her two grandchildren in the US (and hopefully surviving for the next seven years).
There is a desire to lock the gifted money up until both grandchildren are a little bit older (say 30 for example)
My assumption here is US gift tax does not apply (although UK IHT rules would do so)
It feels like a trust would be the best way forward, but are there other alternative vehicles that might be better (I assume a trust would have some ongoing legal fees) say some sort of ETF that locks in funds for 5 years (although that might have US tax issues)
What alternatives should I be looking for?

Setting up an irrevocable trust will have an upfront cost, but should have no ongoing legal costs. Taxes for the trust will need to be filed of course. Make yourself the trustee. Fairly straightforward.

You should discuss it with an attorney.
Generally, if they're not minors they should be able to do with the gift whatever they want. So if the intention is to put conditions on the gift but still relinquish ownership herself - a trust sounds like the way to go. Yes, a trust may have legal and tax implications and ongoing costs. Foreign trusts (with foreign to the US or the UK trustees and beneficiaries) may have additional implications in each of the countries.

There aren’t any attorneys in the UK. She should discuss it with a solicitor.

I'm sure she can find some in the US.
